# Can I fly back to Italy with receipt of renewal of residence permit if I applied for the renewal 2 weeks before my permit expired?

Tags: schengen-visas, italy, permits

I plan on traveling back to my home country for 10 days. I applied for the renewal of my residence permit 2 weeks before it was set to expire. Will it still be a problem? I am asking because in IATA it says: **Applications for renewal must be made within 60 days of expiring, otherwise immigration could refuse re-entry, even if holding confirmation of application**

Does the above statement mean it is okay to have applied for the renewal within 60 days **after** expiring? Because in that case, I guess I am safe. I am sorry but for some reason, my English sentence comprehension collapsed when trying to read the above-highlighted sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I look it up in Timatic, the following comes up:

> - Residents of Italy with an expired Residence Permit  are
>     permitted to re-enter Italy. They must also have a receipt
>     issued by the Italian Post Office or Police Department
>     proving that they have applied for the new residence permit
>     in less than 60 days after the expiration date. They must
>     return to Italy directly from outside the Schengen area.

This means you are OK with the receipt, as it was before 60-days after the expiry of your residence permit.

Keep in mind the second requirement also: Your flight must go directly to Italy as the first Schengen member state on the itinerary. You cannot pass through another Schengen state on the way to Italy when using the receipt to travel.