# Can you travel within the Schengen area with a Permesso di soggiorno renewal receipt?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, italy, permesso-di-soggiorno

I am Indian student in Italy. My [Permesso di soggiorno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permesso_di_soggiorno) recently expired and I applied for renewal. Can I fly from Italy to Budapest with a renewal receipt and no actual permit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated on [the official Polizia di Stato website](https://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10722-Requirements_for_immigrants_leaving_Italy_temporarily):

> Foreigners awaiting renewal of their residence permits can leave and re-enter Italy if they hold:
>
> - The receipt issued by Italian Post offices (Poste Italiane S.p.A) certifying the submission of the application for renewal of their residence permit or EC residence permit for long-term residents;
> - The expired residence permit;
> - Their passport or other equivalent travel document;
> - they do not visit any other Schengen state.

So therefore, it is possible to leave the country and re-enter again with your receipt of renewal, as long as you follow the rules outlined above, but unfortunately you cannot go to Budapest as Hungary is a Schengen country.

Additionally, if you have not requested a renewal but your Residence Permit has expired less than 60 days ago, you can enter Italy as long as you are possession of a valid [Visto di Reingresso](https://portaleimmigrazione.eu/visto-di-reingresso/), which is issued only in the presence of an authorized police station.

Comment: Are you sure the OP is allowed to enter another Schengen country with the receipt? The web page you link to indicates not. See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144513/can-i-fly-back-to-italy-with-receipt-of-renewal-of-residence-permit-if-i-applied