# Travelling back to Italy

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, schengen, italy

I have bad situation. 
I applied for residence permit on 23 Sept 2019 and I left italy the next day 24 Sept 2019. I am in my country untill today and its been more than two months since I last left italy. 
I want to travel back, I have expired residence permit and receivuta. 
Will there be any problem?
Kindly let me know, i will be very thankful to you.
PS: I could not travel because I had some emergency situation.

Comment: Have you visited any other Schengen country since you left Italy? And what is your country of citizenship?

Comment: My citizenship is Pakistani.

Comment: I did not visit any other schengen state. I travelled directly from Italy to my country.

Comment: Then the question tagged above in the comments should answer this. You are fine to return to Italy with an expired permit, receipt of renewal, and current passport, if you have not entered a Schengen country since you left Italy. Your return flight to Italy must be direct as well.

Comment: Actually, a lot of people were telling ne that If i stay more than 60 days outside italy with expired residence permit and receipt, then it will be a problem.

Comment: Yes, it could be a problem if you are gone more than 60 days past the expiry date of your previous residence permit. See the above linked question (different to the one that Traveller suggested). You should contact your nearest Italian consulate for instructions if more than 60 days has actually passed since your permit expired.

Comment: Dear Michael, what I understood from the answers of that question is that, I should have applied residence permit within 60 days after expiration date. ...... there is no such information that I should come back to Italy within 60 days of my permit expiration. Since I have already applied for my residence permit, i suppose it would not be a problem. Wouldn’t it so?

Comment: @ChJunaid As it was explained above, you can return to Italy with the expired residence permit and renewal receipt until 60 days after the expiry date of your residence permit. It does not matter when you made the application for renewal, the 60 days is after the expiry date of the residence permit.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  I am sorry but i could not find the question which you are referring me to. Can you please paste that in comments?

Comment: @ChJunaid It is in the blue box at the top of the page, where it says: **This question already has an answer here: [Can I fly back to Italy with receipt of renewal of residence permit if I applied for the renewal 2 weeks before my permit expired?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/144513/3221)**